# Python BaseHTTPServer serving files faster

Tags: python, file-io, basehttpserver

I have some relatively large .js files (flot and jquery) to serve with a Python BaseHTTPServer.

Currently I am using:

```
with open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'rb') as fd:
    self.wfile.write(fd.read())
```

But its rather slow, even loading the files from the same machine (> a second to fetch these). I imagine this is reading the entire file into RAM and then writing from that, is there a way I can speed this up a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, your code buffers everything before sending it off to the client. To stream the response instead, look at how [`SimpleHTTPServer` does it](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py).

It uses [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj), which does exactly that. Use:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfileobj(fd, self.wfile)
```